# Social icons Twitter and Facebook do not load completely

Tags: javascript, html, twitter, facebook-social-plugins

Having a weird problem with social icons on my page.
G+ is working perfectly but the Twitter Share button + FB Like button do not load up when my html page has finished loading.

Twitter:

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button">Tweet</a>
<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+'://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js';fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document, 'script', 'twitter-wjs');</script>
```

here I only see the plain text "Tweet" (as a link) when the page finished loading. Not the actual twitter button.

Facebook (using some rails code here to display the current URL), here I don't see anything:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script>(function(d, s, id) {
      var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
      if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
      js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
      js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=.......";
      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<div class="fb-like" data-href="<%= request.original_url %>" data-width="100" data-colorscheme="light" data-layout="button_count" data-action="like" data-show-faces="false" data-send="false"></div>
```

Funny thing is:
After the page has loaded and when I hit the reload button (CMD+R), the icons are showing up perfectly!

No idea how to solve that issue.
I have tried to show the content using JS only when the document has finished loading but that did not solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The turbolinks gem caused the problem.

Solved by following these tips here:
http://reed.github.io/turbolinks-compatibility/twitter.html

http://reed.github.io/turbolinks-compatibility/facebook.html

Comment: That solution did not work in my case - broke the buttons completely.  Best solution is to put 'no-turbolinks' in all links pointing to pages with the fb/twitter buttons on them, or remove turbolinks entirely from your app.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
    (function(d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) return;

        js = d.createElement(s);
        js.id = id;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/fr_FR/all.js#xfbml=1";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>

<div class="fb-post"
     data-href="https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?v=10153444775720220"
     data-width="550">
    <div class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore">
        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?v=10153444775720220">
        Publication</a> de
        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/tsahalfr">
        Tsahal-Armée de Défense d&#039;Israël</a>.
    </div>
</div>
```